# Website thumbnail/image/icons not loading properly

Tags: firefox, icons, chromium, youtube, thumbnails

On youtube, the video thumbnails are greyed but the hover previews works. I can click to play a video but the thumbnails would also be grey. On Reddit, the icons appear as square boxes with alphanumeric characters.

Please assist me with this.

- System: Ubuntu 20.04
- Browsers tested and exhibited the same issue: Firefox, chromium
- Things I've tried:

  - Firefox:

    - reinstall firefox,
    - turn on/off enhanced tracking protection, hardware acceleration
    - clear all cookies and data
    - got to about:config -> changing image.webp.enabled to true/false
  - ubuntu: sudo apt update, restart PC

Pictures:

- [youtube on Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbqiW.jpg)
- [youtube on chromium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO7uL.png)
- [reddit icons (Left: the current situation, right: expected view)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGbQV.png)

Comment: If you right click the grey images in Firefox / Chromium, and select "Inspect", what does the Inspector show? Where is it trying to download these images from? (`src` attribute or `<source>` element in a `<picture>`)

Comment: @ՕլՁՅԿ it is not a link. On my linux machine, 
src="data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mN8XA8AAksBZG7LpHYAAAAASUVORK5CYII=">

Any suggestion on how to resolve this?